# Facebook iframe app, problems with php and IE

Tags: php, facebook, internet-explorer

I'm developing a facebook iframe app (page app), which counts the user's friends that had already liked the fan page, and if it has 30 or more friends that had made it will let the user send some images via HTML form.

The app is working great on FF and Chrome, but not in IE. After testing a lot I think I know what the problem is, but not how to solve it.

The thing is that, after successfully installed the app, it redirects you to the same site, but this time instead of asking you to install it will show a quick register form, **the form action sends you to the same index**, but in this step the app will not show the quick register form, it will get the POST variables and calculate the friends that already liked the fan page.

But I had noticed that, after the form call index.php, the app will not run the functions on external PHP files, and since I have an external script with all my functions the app won't work.

So the problem is that when the form call the same index (or any other) the site (app) will not run the functions on external PHP scripts, **but the scripts are successfully included** because if I make an echo at the end of the external script it will be executed.

I have already tried with include, include_once, require and require_once.
The PHP is not showing me any error.
My best guess is something related with the security of IE.

Some of my code.
at index.php, the form:

```
<form action="index.php?liked=1&quickregister=1" method="post">
```

the beginning of index.php:

```
include_once 'scripts/main.php';

    global $facebook;

    $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
```

at main.php:

```
require_once 'db.php';
    require_once 'functions/mail.functions.inc.php';

$fbconfig['appid']     = "************";
$fbconfig['secret']     = "*************************";
$fbconfig['baseurl']    = "my_app_url";

try{
        include_once "facebook.php";
    }
    catch(Exception $o){
        error_log($o);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post some code exemples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost impossible to tell what is going wrong without code snippet. But probably it's IE third part cookie problem. Your application can't "logged in" your users in IE

There are a lot of information about this problem. [link](http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-how-to-get-internet-explorer-to-use-cookies-inside-1612.html)

Comment: i have just adjust the IE options and put the privacy and security setting to the lowest, and got no luck, i will keep trying with your documentation, thanks.